# Mix content issue on tableau to ELB nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, amazon-elb, tableau-api

I have embedded tableau report inside my application using javascript api. In the javascript api, I am getting the tableau report url from the tableau server using trusted authentication and reverse proxy. The application works fine, if the application is deployed without SSL. On my production it is under SSL(https). I have enabled the reverse proxy for the tableau server from the Nginx which is working. But when the call is made using the javascript API it is getting resolved to http call...and it is getting blocked due to SSL.

I have a setup as shown below,

tableau server---->hits https://example.com/xyz--->AWS ELB with SSL certificate--->Nging runs on http protocol.
For https its not working but for http its working fine.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Can you show the javascript API call or that part of the config?